# IIS Manager displays a stopped service as started and prevents me from starting it

Tags: wcf, iis

My IIS service is stopped. However, according to IIS manager the service status is 'started'. Therefore I cannot start it because the "start" option is off. When trying to stop or restart the service I get an error specifying the service has not been started.

How can I start the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embarrassingly, restarting IIS Manager has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can control IIS via the Command Line:

`IISReset /stop`
`IISReset /start`

Also always remember to close and re-open your **IIS Manager** to ensure you are synced up with the current state.